# Efficient way to split a huge string in R

Tags: r, string, stringr, stringi

I have a huge string (> 500MB), actually it's an entire book collection in one. I have some meta information in another dataframe, e.g. page numbers, (different) authors and titles. I try to detect the title strings in my huge string and split it by title. I assume titles are unique.

The data looks like this:

```
mystring <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sollicitudin duis maecenas habitasse ultrices aenean tempus"

# a dataframe of meta data, e.g. page numbers and titles
mydf <- data.frame(page = c(1, 2),
                   title = c( "Lorem", "maecenas"))
mydf

  page   title
1    1   Lorem
2    2 vivamus

mygoal <- mydf  # text that comes after the title
mygoal$text <- c("ipsum dolor sit amet, sollicitudin duis", "habitasse ultrices aenean tempus")
mygoal 

  page   title                                    text
1    1   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sollicitudin duis
2    2 vivamus        habitasse ultrices aenean tempus
```

How can I split the string such that everything between two titles is the first text, everything that comes after the second title and before the third title, becomes the second text element - in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wanted to do the operation in a piped tidyverse way, you could try using `stringr::str_extract` with some regex:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(glue)

mydf |>  
  mutate(next_title = lead(title, default = "$")) |> 
  mutate(text = str_extract(mystring, glue::glue("(?<={title}\\s?)(.*)(?:{next_title})"))) |> 
  select(-next_title)
```

Yielding:

```
page    title                                      text
1    1    Lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet, sollicitudin duis 
2    2 maecenas          habitasse ultrices aenean tempus
```

If performance is a concern, a similar approach with `data.table` would be:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(glue)

mydt <- setDT(mydf)

mydt[, next_title :=shift(title, fill = "$", type = "lead")][
  ,text := str_extract(..mystring, glue_data(.SD,"(?<={title}\\s?)(.*)(?={next_title})"))][,
    !("next_title")]
```

Resulting in:

```
   page    title                                      text
1:    1    Lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet, sollicitudin duis 
2:    2 maecenas          habitasse ultrices aenean tempus
```

**EDIT**

Added for better performance options:

Generally, `str_split` or `str_split_fixed` will be a faster way to go than `str_extract`.

The problem for `str_split` is that  a regex with many alternate pipes will also slow down the process, so another solution would be to replace all the titles in the string first with some fixed character string, and then split on those. Another thing you can do to speed up the splitting is use `str_split_fixed` and pre-assign how many splits to process.

```
    # create named character vector for str_replace_all function
split_at <- rep("@@",nrow(mydf))
names(split_at) <- mydf$title
mystring <- str_replace_all(mystring, split_at)

# used fixed in str_split
mydf$text <- str_split(mystring,fixed("@@ "))[[1]][-1]

# Alternative (maybe faster) define number of splits by nrow
mydf$text <- str_split_fixed(mystring,fixed("@@ "), n = nrow(mydf)+1)[,-1]


## using str_split_fixed in data.table
mydt <- setDT(mydf)
mydt[, text := 
       str_split_fixed(mystring,fixed("@@ "), nrow(mydt)+1)[,-1]
```

Comment: The code works in principle. But I struggle even with the `data.table` option. I select about 1/50 of my text string. The code run for 52min.

Comment: I edited my response with some potentially faster alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `strsplit`

```
mygoal$text <- trimws(strsplit(mystring,
      paste(mydf$title, collapse = "|"))[[1]][-1])
```

-output

```
> mygoal
  page    title                                    text
1    1    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sollicitudin duis
2    2 maecenas        habitasse ultrices aenean tempus
```